# Large images still break bootstrap column with max width and height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap templates that users can use to create displays of images and text, and I earlier added max-width:100% and height:auto to my `img` css which I thought fixed it for certain large images.

However, If I add a huge image into it it still breaks the container.

I'm trying to make it so that a user can drag an image into this container and the image will fit no matter what.

What am I doing wrong?

```
img {
      max-width: 100%; 
      height:auto;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
#topLeftContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
    #bottomLeftContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }
    #rightQtrContent{
      display:flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
    }

<div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">
   <div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
    <div class="col-lg-6"  id="leftColumnQtr">
      <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-bottom: 15px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
            <div  id="topLeftContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="height:50%; padding-top: 15px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:100%;">
            <div id="bottomLeftContent" style=" height: 100%;">
               <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x700">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf" >
        <div id="rightQtrContent" style=" height: 100%; ">
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Image
[image]

Comment: hi if you are using id then use # to represent id in stylesheet. and if you are using class the use dot to represent in stylesheet. you should check the basics.  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Comment: I just corrected that above, that was my error. My source code has a class and ID for each but I didn't copy them both over. But that is not my issue, my issue is that adding very large images to the column breaks the bounds

Comment: Hi. Your HTML source is all div tags. Where will the image insert exactly? It would be easier to see the problem if we could reproduce the issue. My hipfire reaction is you should ditch the inline styles and the problem is related to applying a height of either 50% or 100% which would just fill all of the height of the calculated parent element. Inline styles take precedence over stylesheet rules unless marked with !important.

Comment: and also show us what you are expecting.

Comment: @ThisClark sorry, that was a miss on my part but I added a placeholder image where one would typically be for me. Good point though, maybe I'll try to remove the inline styles first

Comment: @ThisClark That didn't seem to resolve it though, unfortunately. My container is set to 100vh so that my columns all sit within that correctly, and that doesn't seem to be a problem anywhere. My biggest issue now is that I just want to make sure that even if someone saves a very large image into one of the columns that it remains within that column and scales down as needed

Comment: Can you send a drawn image with expected output?@TomN.

Comment: @Sharvan no problem, just added one

Comment: so left and right column will be equal . right side and top left side filled with content right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `img-fluid` for all image in bootstrap 4. Use can use `display:flex` for column to align equally.

```css
.row.middle {
  background-image: url('https://drinknooma.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/placeholder-1170x731.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.row.eqcol div[class^="col-"] {
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid my-container">
   <div class="row eqcol middle" id="middle">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="leftColumnQtr">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="topLeftContent">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="bottomLeftContent">
               <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1500x700">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="rightColumnQtrHalf" >
        <div id="rightQtrContent">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the image isn't hard coded though, can I apply the img-fluid class universally through CSS?

Comment: Yes. Instead of `img-fluid` use can use `max-width: 100%;height: auto;` for all image tags.